# How to include mean in rmvt() in r

Tags: r

There is no parameter for mean unlike `mvrnorm()` for example. How would you include this? I just added `+ mean` to the end of my code `rmvt(200, sigma = sigma1, df = 6) + mean1` but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Edit: I'm using `library(mvtnorm)`

Edit2: I found this listed in the documentation. Unsure if correct.

```
# X ~ t_3(mu, Sigma)
n <- 1000
mu <- 1:2
Sigma <- matrix(c(4, 2, 2, 3), ncol=2)
set.seed(271)
x <- rep(mu, each=n) + rmvt(n, sigma=Sigma, df=3)
plot(x)
```

Comment: What is the package you are talking about?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Updated

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/265557/8402

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Was this the code? ```t(t(mvrnorm(n, rep(0, length(mu)), sigma) * sqrt(nu / rchisq(n, nu))) + mu)``` is equal to ```rmvt(200, sigma = sigma1, df = 6)``` with the mean?

Comment: The answer is essentially "yes, that's right".

Comment: You can use `sweep(rmvt(nsims, sigma=Sigma, df=df), 2, mean1, "+")`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent ```t(t(mvrnorm(n, rep(0, length(mu)), sigma) * sqrt(nu / rchisq(n, nu))) + mu)``` and ```sweep(rmvt(nsims, sigma=Sigma, df=df), 2, mean1, "+")``` give quite different results for me though? Why is this?

Comment: @catzen, I believe the code you're adding (with `sqrt(...)`) is adjusting the *non-centrality* of the t distribution (i.e. it's not what you want). If you have a single mean value then just adding it is fine. @StephaneLaurent's solution works if you have a vector of different mean values for different elements of the multivariate output.

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, I have a vector of means. So ```sweep(rmvt(nsims, sigma=Sigma, df=df), 2, mean1, "+")``` accounts for a vector of means? Whereas ```t(t(mvrnorm(n, rep(0, length(mu)), sigma) * sqrt(nu / rchisq(n, nu))) + mu)``` is for a single value? I looked it up and before there seemed to be a parameter for ```mu``` using ```rmvt```, I don't know why it's not used now.

Comment: @catzen, you mean that `mean1`  is a matrix?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes I have multiple mean values in ```mean1```. ```Sigma``` is a matrix.

Comment: A *long* time ago there was a "mean" parameter: https://github.com/cran/mvtnorm/blob/master/inst/NEWS#L141. I have no idea what kind of "misuse" it was prone to ...